# Given 2 or more tsv files and only a terminal, how can you calculate the average difference of dates that only appear in both?

Tags: awk, csv

Let's say we have some files:

**File 1 (date, value):**

```
20130510\t50000
20130520\t3400
20130601\t4500
```

**File 2 (date, something, value):**

```
20130511\tx\t123
20130520\ty\t456
20130601\tz\t789
```

We want the average of the difference in values associated with the dates that appear in both files.

- 20130520 and 20130601 appear in both (need some kind of filter)
- the difference in values is abs(3400-456) and abs(4500-789)
- the average is (abs(3400-456)+abs(4500-789))/2.0

I can easily do this in Python, but how about with awk in the terminal?

Comment: I'm currently trying, the matching row bit is tricky

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
awk -f a.awk file1 file2
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
BEGIN {FS="\t"}
NR==FNR{
    x[$1]=$2; next
}
$1 in x {
    y[$1]=$3
}
END{
    for (i in y) {
        s=s+abs(x[i]-y[i])
        j++
    }
    print s/j
}
function abs(x){return ((x < 0.0) ? -x : x)}
```

Output:

```
3327.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}
{if ($1 in a) { s+=sqrt((a[$1]-$3)*(a[$1]-$3));i++}}
END{print s/i}' file1 file2
```

#### Explanation

- No need define FS to "\t", because white space has included `tab`
- `sqrt((x-y)*(x-y))` can be easily used for ABS function.